# How open pdf file on android 6

Tags: android, pdf, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need open .pdf file.

In Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In code

```
file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/ccAlTT_D__.pdf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intentOpenFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentOpenFile.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intentOpenFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentOpenFile);
```

Path to file is right.
It do not work on android 6, and it work at version below.
At moment when i clicked button -  pdf file opens, but instantly closes.

At log

```
12-23 14:06:53.248 18679-16520/? E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
12-23 14:06:53.248 18679-16520/? E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : ccAlTT_D__.pdf] +UriOpenable
12-23 14:06:53.381 881-896/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

my manifest full

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="***">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: ca we see your full manifest plz

Comment: @Sree ok, i add manifest in question

Comment: try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Util.DL_DIRECTORY in your file

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> use this

Comment: @Sree I don't understand you. What is that `Util.DL_DIRECTORY`?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria. Your solution not true

Comment: @PavelK you havnt added that in your manifest. cause you are trying to read a file from storage and you have given permission for write

Answer (score 2):

You should not be passing the file to the intent as a file URL, since there is no guarantee that (as here) the receiving application has permission to access that file.

Pass the data from the file via a [`FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) content provider url.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File( filename  );
    intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
    startActivity(intent);


OR


 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: unfortunately first way is not work. 
At log - same that for my code.
Second way  - crash. At log - 
`12-23 14:50:18.564 5664-5664/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/ccAlTT_D__.pdf typ=application/pdf pkg=com.adobe.reader }`